# Converting byte to a single int Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bluetooth

I am implementing a Bluetooth Android application, where Image is sent from one device to another. The bitmap's byte array is sent and successfully reconstructed at the receiver end. However, I need to send a single integer value together with the bitmap as an index(so the receiver knows what to do with the received bitmap). So basically I want to send this in a byte stream:

int|bitmap

Since I need to transfer an int up to 27, that means it fits into a single byte, right? My current code looks like this:

```
ba[0] = Integer.valueOf(drawableNumber).byteValue(); //drawableNumber value is between 1 and 27
 ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  //create new output stream
 try {
     bs.write(ba);         //bytes of the integer
     bs.write(bitmapdata); //bytes of the bitmap
     bs.toByteArray()      // put everything into byte array
}

 mChatService.write(bs.toByteArray()); // that is where bytes are sent to another device
```

And at the receiver end:

```
 case MESSAGE_READ:
    readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;  // readBuf contains ALL the received bytes using .read method
```

So my question is, how can I reconstruct the integer and the image I have sent(basically a single byte to a single integer)? I manage to reconstruct the bitmap alone, but I need this additional integer value to know what to do with the received image. The integer value will always be between 0 and 27. I have checked all other answers, but could not find a proper solution..

**EDIT:** Main question is how to separate the integer bytes from the bitmap bytes in the byte array. Because at the receiving end I want to reconstruct the sent integer AND the bitmap separately

Comment: bytes are 8 bits, an octal. convert the octal to an int?

Comment: @zgc7009 eh? I fail to see where "octal" enters the picture here; "octal" is "base 8" in the same manner that "binary" is "base 2" and "decimal" is "base 10"; it has nothing to do with a `byte`'s internal representation, which uses 8 _bits_

Comment: yea read it wrong :P haven't really done what you are doing before... + a long night. anyway, im adding an answer because it was too much for a comment

Comment: What is `ba` in this code? A `byte[]`?

Comment: I also don't think octal can help me in any way in this situation.. yes, ba as shown in the code is a byte that is converted from an int that has a value of 1 to 27.
ba is defined as: byte[] ba = new byte[1];

Comment: again, just skimmed through what was going on quickly, havent messed with byte arrays before so i thought you were doing bits (misread it) so thought you would have to get the first 8 bits and convert it from the octal. seems that it is even easier passed as a byte seeing as ints can only be a single byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since converting a byte to an int is a downcast, you can just assign the byte to an int variable.

```
int myInt = ba[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try this in java, it simply tells me what my mind was thinking when I commented. An integer is represented as a byte (so in your case, it is simply ba[0]). Or it should be based on your code. Any more than that and it would be a long. That means it is also the first byte that will get read out of your buffer (or should be).

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;


public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        byte[] ba = new byte[10];
        int myInt = 13;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  //create new output stream

        try {
           bs.write(myInt);         //bytes of the integer
           ba = bs.toByteArray();      // put everything into byte array
        } finally{};

        for(int i = 0; i < ba.length; i++){
          System.out.println(i);
          System.out.println(ba[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Again I realize this isn't exactly an answer, just too much for a comment.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but my main question is how to separate the integer bytes from the bitmap bytes in the byte array. Because at the receiving end I want to reconstruct the sent integer AND the bitmap separately... thanks